# Nextjs dynamic routing system with folder. How it knows which folder to choose if theres multiple dynamic ones?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, next.js, frontend

So if in the same folder you have 3 dynamic folders under products -> [a],[b],[c] , how can nextjs know which folder to pick for when you go products/[2]. Im not sure if thats a real life scenario to have a couple of dynamic folders but im still curious

copy and pasted a dynamic folder in the same directory where I changed their names but still nextjs somehow picked the right one.

Comment: It's not valid; you shouldn't have different dynamic routes on the same level.